# What is the difference between で and に when it comes to words like 溢れる?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence, and I was wondering, how would the nuance change if I changed the で to に?  
この街は異邦人**で**あふれている


この街は異邦人**に**あふれている

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not clearcut distinction, but roughly,

- に is less frequently used in speech
- に is used more often with non-tangible objects.

Conversely, I feel で is kind of more neutral.

To me, 異邦人にあふれている is a little odd, possibly because 異邦人 is a physical object.

Most common examples with に would be やさしさ/活気/希望にあふれた (*full of tenderness/liveliness/hope*).

---

Note that に can be the standard location particle as in 世の中**に**あふれた怪しい話 (literally *fishy stories of which there's plenty **in** the world*).

Comment: Do you think similar stuff applies to any kind of verb that uses に and its meaning is something close to "being full"? As in 満ちる?

Comment: @prdelsmradkava As for に満ちた, yes. And I guess 満ちた more often comes with に (i.e., it comes with intangible object). But いっぱい cannot really take に. It always comes with で (regardless of the tangibility). E.g. 幸せでいっぱい.